# How does this circuit work?

Tags: circuits

I saw a [Computerphile](https://youtu.be/XETZoRYdtkw) video explaining how a simple circuit could store memory using some logic gates.

However, I couldn't wrap my mind around
 how one could find the value of q if one needs not, which in turn needs q, etc.

**EDIT:**
q is the output of a logic gate and at the same time the input of another logic gate. not q is also an input and an output.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Please [edit] your question to make it self-contained.  What is `q`?  Please define your notation.  Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. First you could link to the video. Second you could give an example and say what you mean by "find the value of `q` if one needs `not`, which in turn needs `q`, etc."

Comment: Wait I thought I linked it?

Comment: I still don't think we have enough context.  The question needs to be self-contained, so we can understand it without clicking on an external link.  Without knowing what specific circuit you're thinking of, I don't think this can be answered.

Comment: @D.W. Alright I will edit it later to be self-contained.